# LastModifiedDate on Parent Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, system-fields

If we edit the Parent Opportunity (Parent_Opportunity__c) field On an opportunity, It was observed that LastModifiedDate of both parent and child opportunity get updated.Last Modified Date was getting updated automatically when we change the look up field.

But today when i modify/delete child opportunities on a opportunity then it is not updating the LastModifiedDate on parent opportunities.

I have checked this behavior in Sandbox environment.

Can anyone know the reason for why it is not happening so?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Have you got a trigger on Opportunity that is using this custom relationship to update the child?

Comment: Yes you are right. I also observed that if you delete child opportunity, LastModifiedDate on opportunity doesn't get updated.

Comment: @DougB We don't have any trigger which was doing this. Last Modified Date was getting updated automatically when we change the look up field.

Answer (score 1):

> It was observed that LastModifiedDate of both parent and child opportunity get updated.Last Modified Date was getting updated automatically when we change the look up field.

This has to have been from a Trigger, Future Method, Visualforce, or some other Apex transaction, because an operation on a child does not update the parent in a lookup relationship.

Based on a good bit of experience, the functionality you are now experiencing is how it is expected.